# How to fix device camera not support issue in mobile browser React Js

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, google-chrome, mobile-safari

I have created a React Js web application;  using dialog component to open the camera and capture live images. This works fine in desktop browsers, but not in mobile phones and Apple devices. But in Safari browser it works perfectly. How can I make this work in other browsers as well?

```
                      <Dialog 
                            fullScreen={fullScreen}
                            open={this.state.open}
                            onClose={this.handleClose}
                            aria-labelledby="responsive-dialog-title">
                            <DialogTitle className={"testClassForStyle"} id="responsive-dialog-title">{<Translate
                                id={"webCam"}></Translate>}</DialogTitle>
                            <DialogContent className={"camscreen"}>
                                <div className={"webCamCss"}>
                                    <center><Webcam
                                        audio={false}
                                        height={200}
                                        ref={this.setRef}
                                        screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
                                        width={350}/></center>

                                    <center><Button onClick={this.capture} className="btn-success text-white">
                                        <Translate
                                            id={"capture"}></Translate></Button></center>
                                </div>
                            </DialogContent>
                            <DialogActions id="actions-btns">
                                <Button onClick={this.handleClose} className="btn btn-default text-white" autoFocus>
                                    <Translate id={"cancel"}></Translate>
                                </Button>
                                <Button onClick={this.handleAddClose} className="btn btn-primary text-white">
                                    <Translate id={"addBtn"}></Translate>
                                </Button>
                            </DialogActions>
                        </Dialog>
```

Comment: damn! no answer to this question yet